# Call a specific switch case from a class

Tags: c#, wpf, brush, colorbar, colormap

I'm working with WPF (VS C# Express 2010) and I have defined a class that basically acts as a colormap, and it has many cases (Jet, Autumn, Winter, ...). What I want to do is to define the brush color calling a specific case from the main window. This is the code (just cut to 1 case) of the class:

```
public SolidColorBrush[] ColormapBrushes()
    {
        byte[,] cmap = new byte[ColormapLength, 4];
        double[] array = new double[ColormapLength];
        switch (ColormapBrushType)
        {
            case ColormapBrushEnum.Spring:
                for (int i = 0; i < ColormapLength; i++)
                {
                    array[i] = 1.0 * i / (ColormapLength - 1);
                    cmap[i, 0] = AlphaValue;
                    cmap[i, 1] = 255;
                    cmap[i, 2] = (byte)(255 * array[i]);
                    cmap[i, 3] = (byte)(255 - cmap[i, 2]);
                }
                break;
        return SetBrush(cmap);
    }
```

And in my main window I have this:

```
ColormapBrush cb = new ColormapBrush();
SolidColorBrush[] brush = cb.ColormapBrushes(); //Here, how can I specify??
SolidColorBrush brushvalor = cb.GetBrush(......);
lbl.Background = brushvalor;
```

As you can see in the comentary, I'm stuck as I do not know how to specify that I want the case Spring in order to set the colorbar desired. PS: The name of the class is ColormapBrush.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change your `ColormapBrushes` to take a parameter, rather than using the `ColormapBrushType` field. Then call it like `cb.ColormapBrushes(ColormapBrushEnum.Spring)`

Comment: nice idea! Which kind of parameter should I put in this function then?

Comment: The parameter type should be `ColormapBrushEnum`, so something like: `public SolidColorBrush[] ColormapBrushes(ColormapBrushEnum colormapBrushType)` then.. `switch (colormapBrushType) { ... }`

Comment: Can you please clarify. Surely you are not actually asking a question that boils down to "my method needs to know this value, how do I get the value into the method?" I don't know what `SetBrush()` does, but clearly you already know how to write a method that accepts a parameter, and presumably comprehend that doing so is a effective way to provide a method with a value it needs. If would help if you'd provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a precise, detailed explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.